# How to encrypt data that can be decrypted for fixed duration

Tags: go, encryption

My use case looks like this:

1. encrypt some super secret data using a key provided by user
2. when requested, ask the user for that key and decrypt the data
3. re-encrypt the data with a key that will allow my program to access the data for a user defined period of time
4. if token expired ask user for original key again

This feels like it should be a solved problem by my googlefu is weak today.

I could just decrypt the data and store it with a known key in my program but cracking my code would expose those secrets.

I could and maybe should, use some local secure storage for this data like macos keychain etc but i'd like to keep the amount of native variations to a minimum.

Comment: Do you want the decrypting end to say "I refuse to attempt to decrypt this, because it is too late"? Or do you want the (potentially hostile) decrypting end to be *unable to* decrypt because it's too late? I don't see how the latter is possible, given that it's always possible to pretend the wallclock time is anything you like.

Comment: Indeed i want the latter. I did figure this might be impossible but i thought it was worth question to see if anyone had any clever ideas.
in terms of just including a time lock into the code then i would just include a encrypted time into blob im storing so i can check its age on decryption

Comment: You never use "clever ideas" in cryptography. You can rely on proven implementations based on solid research, or you can have broken cryptography.

Comment: If you want a service that can provide these constraints, take a look at something like https://www.vaultproject.io/

Comment: By clever ideas I mean an encryption technique that I am not aware of. Sadly it is very hard to keep abreast of all developments in all areas of programming. 

Vault is a fantastic service we use heavily at my day job, I am looking for this to be part of a open source cli tool

Comment: The closest you can get is probably something akin to [TOTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time-based_One-time_Password_algorithm), though it would still be vulnerable to attack by anyone who either knew when it was supposed to be valid or was willing to brute-force time periods until they hit it.

Comment: The only way to achieve that is to have some server validating the time by decrypting some key or something, AFAIK.

Comment: Where would the (temporarily) decrypted reside? Against whom are you trying to protect that data? (For example, do you want to decrypt and re-encrypt the data on the user's device---user being the person providing the original decryption key? And you want to protect that data when device is seized by law enforcment? Or... ?)

Comment: The only way I can imagine to achieve this is to encode the decryption key on a medium that will decay over time, such as a radioactive substance. To my knowledge, this technology has never been created, except perhaps in experimental quantum computing contexts.

Comment: Is there something preventing you from re-encrypting with your own key, and then you delete that key as soon as it's "expired"?

Comment: Cryptography which relies on the non-existence of closed timelike curves is best avoided. Sorry, I will have been wanted to say: has best been avoided tomorrow.

Comment: @erickson, yes i want to store the data back onto the client device. Essentially what i want an encrypted cache so that i don't have to ask the user for their key every time they run my cmd. I don't want to use a fixed key as that could easily be extracted from the binary. I think i'll just accept that risk and mitigate it with some basic obfuscation

Comment: Why all the hassle when the data resides on the user's device anyway? Simply let him decrypt the data locally into memory. So there we have our data on rest encryption. Once you have access to the data, you can store it away, either way. Period.

Comment: User devices can be compromised. Holding the data in memory for an extended period of time (Several hours), unencrypted, is a significant risk.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this specific question appears to be, no it is not possible to do locally.

The best solution to this kind of problem, ie a temporary cache of data decrypted with a user's key is to either use security tooling present on the users machine, ie macos keychain or to simply re-encrypt the cache with a key known to the program and except that it is possible to reverse engineer that program to find the decryption key.

My plan to deliver this is to generate an encryption key when the program is first run, use that + a known salt to encrypt my cache. The idea being that both the program, the generated key and the cache would need to be compromised together to decrypt my cache.